# Memory Leak using datePicker.datePickerMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, datepicker

I'm creating a custom view that includes a date picker.  My app is running slow, and instruments is showing I have a memory leak.  The line causing the leak is:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have no idea why this is causing a leak.   Entire method below.

```
- (UIView *)createDemoView
{
    UIView *demoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 260)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 60);
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    textView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cochin" size:13];
    textView.text = @"Please Enter Your Birthday";
    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-18,50,162,162)]; //-10.0f, 40.0f, 130.0f, 200.0f)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [demoView addSubview:textView];
    [demoView addSubview:datePicker];
    return demoView;
}
```

Comment: Are you profiling on the device or the Simulator? Ignore anything memory related on the simulator.

Comment: there seems to be nothing wrong with the code you posted here.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  It seems to work fine.